# nginx reverse Proxy some url can't be access

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

i have some issue for something...

i want to make some proxy pass to some url..

```
server {
listen 80;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://www.xxx.xxx/;
  }  
}
```

but the problems was : when i go to some url with http://109.365.52.12/user.php?user=gigantic i was go to the url it use http://www.xxx.xxx. but i dont want it i want it still in my url..

Comment: The Server block is not complete, please show us the complete block

Comment: `proxy_set_header        Host $http_host; ` seems for IMHO to be missing

Comment: i just make that server block.. because i just want to make some kind of iframe if not in ngiins... but somekind of url was can't be do that.. so i asking how to fix that...

Comment: However to be easier, i suggest we chat on https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126791/thechat

Comment: i can't talk because i need to do something with 20 but i dont know.. can you helping me with this??? and not to go there???

Comment: i already told you to add the host header to your block,, remind if its a public site that you will end in a redirect loop if you use http to https and https to http

Comment: what i want to know is *host $http_host; this was the one i copy all.. or its need somethingg to change?? with the url?? because i already try to input this.. and its still problem sir...

Comment: `server { listen 80; location / { proxy_pass http://www.xxx.xxx/; proxy_set_header Host http_host; }  ` remind that the page must be http in case of http is used

Comment: alright i try it first....

Comment: hi there.. i make like you said.. but it was some problems... Error 1003 Ray ID: 66e0bacaa9550ace • 2021-07-13 07:17:06 UTC
Direct IP access not allowed i got this was error.. when i do like that....

Comment: Please update your question instead of single comment answers, also post the LOG about the issues

Comment: i really new in here... and i dont know how.. but the i you ask me to try its really not working man... please really helping me... because i new in nginx and i want to learn about it...

Comment: you have an edit buttn down below your question, use it. However, please update your question because it is stil for me a X and Y problem

Comment: what you mean update my question?? its really my question sir. i use nginx only for to make nginx reverse proxy..... but some kind i can't use for the reverse proxy..

Comment: i give up, you are not willing to cooperate and accepting the basic rules of this Site.